# display calendar using Exchange EWS API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my project i am using MVC, C#, razor...

I am sucessfully using EWS to create appointments on my calendar.
However i have no idea how to display a calendar using EWS.

For what i gathered i need to do a GETAppointments on EWS and after that use some other nugget to display a calendar using those appointments i got from the  GET.

I searched on the web and found a nugget called daypilot(asp.net), however i cant seem to adapt it to my project and cant find any alternatives.

Cant really find any good tutorials on the matter, or maybe i'm just searching for the wrong topics...

Any ideas, or links to good tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future that may be having the same issue, i will post a copy of some parts of my solution:

webservice i created:

```
    public IEnumerable<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment> getAppointments(string userName, string userPwd)
    {

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddYears(1);
        const int NUM_APPTS = 5;

        ExchangeService serviceExchange = ExchangeWebService.ConnectToService(userName, userPwd);


        // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
        CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(serviceExchange, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());

        // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

        // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
        cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);

        // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
        FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);


        return appointments;
    }
```

Then on controller:

```
    public JsonResult AllCalendarApp()
    {
        WebServiceBO webServiceBO = new WebServiceBO();
        var CalendarAppointments = webServiceBO.getAppointments(User.Identity.Name, this.Session["UserPass"].ToString());

        List<string> listAllAppontments = new List<string>();

        List<calendario> listAllAppontmentss = new List<calendario>();
        foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment item in CalendarAppointments)
        {
            listAllAppontmentss.Add(new calendario() { title = item.Subject, start = item.Start });
        }

        return Json(listAllAppontmentss, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And finally on the View:

```
        <div id='calendar'></div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/BackOffice/AllCalendarApp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false,

                events: data
                });
        }
    })


});
```

I used fullcalender to display the calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/).